# Who demonstrated plasmodium life cycle? Grassi or Laveran

Tags: history, experiment, parasitism, malaria

Plasmodium causes malaria which goes through mosquito female anapheles through some of its life stages. But I am not sure which scientist experimentally demonstrated the life cycle of plasmodium. In texts, I found following text which talks about the work of Grassi in 1898:

[image: text screenshot]

And following data supports the fact that Laveran also worked on the life cycle of plasmodium in 1880 which is even way before than Grassi's 1898 experiment.

> By chance, but also thanks to his tenacity and patience, he had seen the exflagellation of a male gametocyte, a phase in the life cycle of malaria parasites which usually occurs in the stomach of the Anopheles mosquito.
> https://www.cdc.gov/malaria/about/history/laveran.html